# Is there a way how you can only get datasets between two dates?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I was wondering if there is a way to only get Datasets between two dates (to be specific hours example: between 5pm and 6pm). I would have to make an Select and it only should return the datasets between 5 and 6 pm. Is there a way where you can do this easily?

Edit: here is the SQL code:

```
Select fahrten_id, StartOrt, Zielort, abfahrt FROM fahrten WHERE ' + $von + ' <= abfahrt AND abfahrt <= ' + $bis + '
```

the "abfahrt" is the date which should be checked.

Edit2:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$server = "---";
$username = "---";
$password = "---";
$database = "---";
$von = $_POST["von"];
$bis = $_POST["bis"];
$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);
     $sql = "Select fahrten_id, StartOrt, Zielort, abfahrt FROM fahrten WHERE '$von' <= abfahrt AND abfahrt <= '$bis'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($con);
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($_POST) . ');';
?>
```

Here is the PHP from the code, i only removed the pw and username and servername

Comment: Sounds like a very simple thing to do, but we would need some code of what you have so far in order to help.

Comment: Need code. Need to know what the database server is. Need to know if you stored the dates in `DATETIME` or just as character data. Etc.

Comment: Also, please edit your tags to contain the RDBMS you're using MySQL, Oracle, SQL-Server. The best solution is likely to be dependent on which DB you ue.

Comment: Go ahead and update the question with the PHP code for the line running the query since you obviously have PHP syntax errors to deal with here. (i.e. `+` vs `.`)

Comment: Can you show us what values `$von` and `$bis` dates take, and what the output is? As it is, we can only guess what the problem is, since we don't have a complete statement to look at. The query broadly looks OK - are these variables just date stamps and not date+time stamps?

Comment: OK, to start with you have a serious security vulnerability: SQL injection. That needs fixing before you go live. So, again, what is the format of the dates you are passing to it?

Comment: Thanks i will take a look at the SQL injection as soon as the other problems are fixed! We are using datetime for the dates with this format:  2015-01-22 00:00:00(YY-DD-MM-HH-Min-SEC)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extract the hour from the date field. Then just limit the result to the hour(s) you want.

```
where Hour( DateField ) >= 17 and Hour( DateField ) < 18
```

This will pass any date where the time field is "17:00:00.00000" to "18:59:59.99999" (or however far the millis go). If you want an inclusive result, change the comparison:

```
where Hour( DateField ) between 17 and 18
```

This will include times that are exactly "18:00:00.00000". (It could happen!)